# как пользоваться assert php

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

Не понимаю как это работает,

```
assert(true == false);
echo 'Привет!';
```

как не меняю, постоянно отдает true,

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.assert.php

Comment: напишите ответ на свой вопрос вместо апдейта вопроса. Тогда этот топик будет иметь смысл для ресурса.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос содержится в руководстве, которое автор не удосужился прочитать до конца)

Comment: читал и перечитывал, просто не знал, что в openserver это значение в -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zend.assertion 
1: генерирует и выполняет код (режим разработки)
0: генерирует код, но перепрыгивает через него во время выполнения
-1: не генерирует код (рабочий режим)

поменял в конфиге openserver zend.assertions с -1 на 1 и все заработало